# Why am I unable to use LDAPFilter in function?

Tags: .net, powershell

I have a gui that I am creating for our Service Desk team. Everything is working correctly. I decided to create a function for unlocking users as we have a couple of different domains. This way, I can pull in the username and server as needed.

When utilizing the following function, I am receiving

> ```
> Get-ADUser : The search filter cannot be recognized
> At line:200 char:17
> +     $Username = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(sAMAccountName=$UsernameToUnlock)"
> +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8254,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
> ```

If I remove the function properties and use it in on a button, it works fine.

Note that for testing purposes, I removed the $Server variable from the function. It is still being passed, but not used.

Ideas?

```
Function Unlock-ADUser{
    Param([string]$Server,[String]$UsernameToUnlock)

    $Username = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(sAMAccountName=$UsernameToUnlock)"

        If ($Username -eq $Null){
             $ActivityConsole.AppendText($DateTime + ": Unlock failed. Username does not exist on the RxOptions.local domain`r`n")
        }Else{

            $DomainControllers = Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | sort | Select-Object name

            Foreach($DC in $DomainControllers)
             {
                 unlock-adaccount -identity $Username
             } 

            $ActivityConsole.AppendText($DateTime + ": " + $Username + " has been unlocked`r`n")
        }

}
```

Comment: What input are you providing for the `-UsernameToUnlock` argument?

Comment: The parameter would pull in an inputed username 'tsmith5' for example.

Comment: Here is an example call,     Unlock-ADUser("rxoptions.local",$UnlockUsername)

Comment: Try wrapping the filter expression in an explicit operator: `"(&(sAMAccountName=$UsernameToUnlock))"`. If that doesn't help: make sure you sanitize whatever input you're getting from the GUI! Test with a debugger (or a simple `Write-Host` statement inside the function) that the strings is exactly what you expect

Comment: Ahh, there's your problem - the syntax for calling PowerShell functions with positional parameters is not `function($arg1,$arg2)`, but rather `function $arg1 $arg2`. Change the call to `Unlock-ADUser "server.name" $UnlockUsername` :)

Comment: Cheers Mathias! That worked, I appreciate it.

Comment: Put that as an answer too that while calling the function the structure is `FunctionName Arg1 Arg2` or `FunctionName -Parameter1 arg1 -parameter2 arg2`